# What's wrong with my svn:ignore pattern?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have the pattern `svn:ignore datasheets/*/*.pdf`
It is supposed to ignore all pdfs that are at an arbitrary depth under multiple "datasheet" directories under the current root folder.

As an example: say I have a dir structure like this

```
Websites
  -web1
    -dataSheets
      -AT
        -ignore.pdf
      -BE
         -NL
          -ignore.pdf
         -FR
          -ignore.pdf
          -ignore2.pdf
    -licenseAgreements
      -important.pdf
  -web2
    -datasheets
      -etc
```

In this example the pattern needs to ignore all the ignore.pdfs without ingoring the important.pdf too.

The shown pattern still includes all my pdf files.

I know there are a bunch of similar questions, but none of them seem to tackle the problem with the various hierarchy levels.

Comment: Please add (to the question, not as a comment) the output of some svn commands that indicate how the pattern is failing. E.g. svn status, before and after changing some PDF:s.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I've added the shown pattern to the properties of the root, added pdfs in any of the lower directories are not ignored

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.ignore):

> [U]nlike the `global-ignores` option, the patterns found in the `svn:ignore` property apply only to the directory on which that property is set, and not to any of its subdirectories.

You need to apply the ignore pattern to each directory recursively, which you can do using the `--recursive` option.

Comment: sadly the example given is not the real situation. In my real world case there are many datasheet folders and the folders will come and go. Applying it each time would be madman's work

Answer (score 1):

You should use the build in **global-ignores** feature. ignoring with svn properties will work only on a single level and yes, you have to change them or re-add them if new folders will be added.

So use the client feature of global-ignores which can be found in your local configuration [around line 94, look for "global-ignores].

Local config can be found under:

windows:

```
%APPDATA%\subversion\config
```

*nix

```
~/.subversion/config
```

Comment: He doesn't want to ignore all PDFs, only most of them.

Comment: I thought he want to ignore all pdfs of a certain filename, but not to ignore other filenames

Answer (score 0):

svn:ignore works only on directory its been set. To ignore files under subdirectories you have to apply this property recursively to subdirs. (-R switch).

Please try this:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*pdf" -R datasheets
```

Comment: it's still adding all the pdfs :S

Answer (score 0):

I am 80% sure you cannot do what you want out-of-the box.  Look into a post-commit hook -- you can evaluate the pathname of the file being added and reject it if it meets the criteria you specify.